# scrolling image in UIScrollView in iphone

Tags: iphone, image, scroll

i m working one app .in this random number of time image is scroll..and then stop the image..here in my code first random number is generate which is store in n..for eg. random no is generate 12 then 12 times image is scroll after that it stop..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
int n = 1 + arc4random() % 10 + 10;

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",n];

    //lbl.text = string;

    NSUInteger i;
    for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
    {


       // [kNumImages addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", i];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
        rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
        imageView.frame = rect;
        imageView.tag = i;  
        lbl.text = string;
        [FirstScrollView addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];

        if(n == i){
          break;       

    }

}
```

i want to stop scrolling when random no is match means `n == i` how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
int n = 1 + arc4random() % 10 + 10;

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",n];

    //lbl.text = string;

    NSUInteger i;
    for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
    {
        if(n == i)
          break;
        else {

       // [kNumImages addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", i];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
        rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
        imageView.frame = rect;
        imageView.tag = i;  
        lbl.text = string;
        [FirstScrollView addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];

          }    

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[firstScrollView setContentOffset:CGRectMake(n*firstScrollView.frame.size.width,firstScrollView.frame.size.height)];

All you need is to set content offset of your scrollView.